# Redirect to GET action method from POST action method in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, ef-core-3.1

I'm trying to create a web app for tracking patient medication in pharmacies using EF CORE and MVC but I've run into an issue.  I have a view set up for creating a script using basic CRUD operations which works fine but I'm not trying to implement additional functionality.  Specifically, I want the ability to add multiple items onto a single script.  I have my DB and the existing views updated but I'm trying to figure out the best way to make this work.

I have a GET controller action which creates an instance of my view model given the id of the patient. My form then posts to either an action that simply creates a single item script or an action which will create a script, add the item then redirect back to the create view in order to add another item to the same script.

Is there a way to redirect from the post action back to the get action in my controller and pass a few parameters at the same time?

**GET action**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(
            int id,
            string sort,
            string currentFilter,
            string search,
            int? pageNumber)
        {
            ViewData["NameSortParam"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sort) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewData["PackSortParam"] = sort == "pack" ? "pack_desc" : "pack";
            ViewData["GenSortParam"] = sort == "gen" ? "gen_desc" : "gen";
            ViewData["StockSortParam"] = sort == "stock" ? "stock_desc" : "stock";
            ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sort;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                pageNumber = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                search = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = search;


            var drugs = from drug in _context.Drug
                        join generic in _context.Generic on drug.GenericId equals generic.Id
                        select drug;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                drugs = drugs.Where(d => d.Name.Contains(search)
                                || d.Generic.Name.Contains(search));
            }

            switch (sort)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    drugs = drugs.OrderByDescending(d => d.Name);
                    break;
                case "pack":
                    drugs = drugs.OrderBy(d => d.PackSize);
                    break;
                case "pack_desc":
                    drugs = drugs.OrderByDescending(d => d.PackSize);
                    break;
                case "cost":
                    drugs = drugs.OrderBy(d => d.CostPrice);
                    break;
                case "cost_desc":
                    drugs = drugs.OrderByDescending(d => d.CostPrice);
                    break;
                case "gen":
                    drugs = drugs.OrderBy(d => d.Generic.Name);
                    break;
                case "gen_desc":
                    drugs = drugs.OrderByDescending(d => d.Generic.Name);
                    break;
                case "stock":
                    drugs = drugs.OrderBy(d => d.StockQty);
                    break;
                case "stock_desc":
                    drugs = drugs.OrderByDescending(d => d.StockQty);
                    break;
                default:
                    drugs = drugs.OrderBy(d => d.Name);
                    break;
            }

            drugs = drugs.Include(d => d.Generic);

            int pageSize = 5;

            var patient = await _context.Patient.FindAsync(id);

            var vm = new NewScriptViewModel()
            {
                Patient = patient,
                PatientId = patient.Id,
                Prescribers = await _context.Prescriber.ToListAsync(),
                Drugs = await PaginatedList<Drug>.CreateAsync(drugs.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize)

            };
            ViewData["PrescriberId"] = new SelectList(_context.Prescriber, "Id", "FullName", patient.PrescriberId);


            return View(vm);
        }
```

**POST action - add next item to same script**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(bool FirstItem, [Bind("PatientId, PrescriberId")] Script script, [Bind("DrugId, Qty, Directions")] ScriptDrug scriptDrug)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (FirstItem)
                {
                    //create script
                    _context.Add(script);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    //add item
                    scriptDrug.ScriptId = script.Id;
                    var drug = _context.Drug.Find(scriptDrug.DrugId);
                    drug.StockQty -= scriptDrug.Qty;
                    _context.Add(scriptDrug);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    //redirect to create to add new item to same script

                }
            }
            //redirect back to view
        }
```

Hopefully I've explained this adequately, but let me know if i need to provide any extra info.

**NB:
Viewmodel**

```
    public class NewScriptViewModel

    {
        public int ScriptId { get; set; }
        public Patient Patient { get; set; }
        public int PatientId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Prescriber> Prescribers { get; set; }
        public int PrescriberId { get; set; }
        public PaginatedList<Drug> Drugs { get; set; }
        public int DrugId { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public string Directions { get; set; }
        public bool FirstItem { get; set; }

        public NewScriptViewModel()
        {
            FirstItem = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try just calling your get action `return Create(/*add my parameters here*/)` from your post action?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, esotericbob!

Yes, the `Post/Redirect/Get` is a very common and very desired to be followed pattern. It can prevent You or Your userrs to acidently trigger the same `POST` request twice. If You already know that, sorry, just for a clarification.

I've created a little example for You, I hope this is what You are looking for:

**HomeController.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication4.Controllers
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using WebApplication4.Models;

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new MyModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(MyModel model)
        {
            ViewBag.additionalData = "Something";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Home\Index.cshtml**

```
@model MyModel

Get view

<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="@Model.Data" />
    <button type="submit">Post!</button>
</form>

Additional data: @ViewBag.additionalData
```

**MyModel.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication4.Models
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The workflow is as follows:

- Start with `[GET] Home\Index`. We will end up within the `[GET] Index` method.
- `return View(new MyModel());` will return to us the `Views\Home\Index.cshtml` (by convention) with new empty model to be filled with the form.
- we fill form values, send data with `POST` method (no `action` or `controller` attributes within `<form>` tag as by convention it will send `[POST] Home\Index` and get us to the same controller and same named action but `POST` version on it)
- we utilize `ViewBag` to keep additional data for the call
- then we call just `View()` to call the `Home\Index` (again by convention calling controller with the same name and view same as the method's name)
- by default it will request another `[GET] Home\Index` and we are back where we have started but with some extra value to use inside `ViewBag` (which will be gone if we redirect/refresh).